# If $\{X_n\}$ is a finite, aperiodic, irreducible Markov chain, what is $\displaystyle\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{X_i^2}{n}$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

If $\{X_n\}$ is a finite, aperiodic, irreducible Markov chain,I want to find the limit$$\displaystyle\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{X_i^2}{n}$$ given that it's stationary distribution is $\{\pi_1,...,\pi_k\}$ and the transition matrix $P=\{p_{ij}\}_{1\leq i,j \leq k}.$ I am not sure if I can use the strong law of large numbers here since I do not know if $X_i^2$s are i.i.d. I am tempted to say that $$\displaystyle\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{X_i^2}{n}=1^2\pi_1+2^2\pi_2+...+k^2\pi_k$$ but I have no way to justify this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In any interesting case, the $X_i$ will *not* be i.i.d., but you are right to be tempted.

Comment: @kimchilover Then maybe use weak law of large numbers?

Comment: The same iid problem exists there, too.  What do you know in general about  aperiodic irreducible chains?

Comment: No, the standard laws of large numbers are all for independent variables. But if you google "law of large numbers for markov chains" you should find some stuff of interest. This is a corollary of the ergodic theorem.

Comment: @kimchilover that it has a limiting distribution

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen oh yes indeed. Thank you

Comment: The ergodic theorem says that the limiting distribution is equal to the limiting frequency of visits to the states.. you can extend this to the expectation values.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't understand as to what you mean by "extend this to the expectation values"

Comment: Apologies, that was poor phrasing. I meant you could use it to straightforwardly prove that $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i) = \sum_{j=1}^{N_s} f(j) \pi_j$$ where the state space is $\{1,2,\ldots, N_s\}.$ Also, a minor quibble with what was said above: it is not true that every irreducible, aperiodic markov chain has a stationary distribution. However it is true if you add the condition that there are a finite number of states. (You may know this, but in case you don't.)

Comment: $\pi_k$ is the proportion of time the chain is in state $k$.